# Inserting data into table using instead of trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. Table A with structure as follows.

   ```
   ID (PK), Name, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10,
   created-user, created-date, modified-user, modified-date
   ```
2. Table B with structure as follows.

   ```
   ID, Table name, Name
   ```

Steps to carry out while inserting data.

1. Data for Table A will be sent by Java application. So data will be supplied from Java application.
2. Take the data sent by Java application and validate the same. A procedure has been written which will generate the output as below.

   ```
   Insert into Table A (Name, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10)
        Values (‘Mod1’, ‘ACB1’, NULL, NULL,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
   ```
3. In the same procedure insert statement will be executed.
4. Instead of  Trigger has been written for following.
   a.  Generate ID using SEQ MASTER
   b.  Execute [P_TRG_ACTION] and update the ID, Tablename (TableA), Name (Mod1) into Table B.

   ```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_ME_ADAPTER_CU] ON [dbo].[ME_ADAPTER_CU]
   instead of INSERT, update, delete

   AS

   BEGIN

     DECLARE @P_EVENT VARCHAR(max)
       ,@P_NEW_ID int
       ,@P_N_CRTDATE DATETIME2(0)
       ,@P_N_CRTUSER VARCHAR(max)
       ,@P_TNAME VARCHAR(max)
       ,@P_NAME VARCHAR(max)
       ,@P_N_MODDATE DATETIME2(0)
       ,@P_N_MODUSER VARCHAR(max)


   DECLARE cur_row CURSOR local for select id, NAME from inserted

   /* For insert operation-------------*/

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)

   BEGIN

   OPEN cur_row
           FETCH NEXT FROM cur_row INTO @P_NEW_ID, @P_NAME

           WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0

           BEGIN
           SET @P_NEW_ID = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ_MASTER

                   SELECT @P_EVENT = 'I'
                       ,@P_TNAME = '[dbo].TABLE A'
                       FROM inserted
                   SELECT @P_NAME FROM inserted
                   select @P_N_CRTDATE = GETDATE();
                   select @P_N_CRTUSER= CURRENT_USER;


                   EXEC [dbo].[P_TRG_ACTION]  
                       @P_EVENT
                       ,@P_NEW_ID
                       ,@P_N_CRTDATE
                       ,@P_N_CRTUSER
                       ,@P_TNAME
                       ,@P_NAME

           FETCH NEXT FROM cur_row INTO @P_NEW_ID, @P_NAME 

       end

       close cur_row
       deallocate cur_row
   END
   ```

**P_trg_action**

```
USE [MEV2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[P_TRG_ACTION]    Script Date: 7/2/2015 9:51:06 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_TRG_ACTION]  


  @P_EVENT varchar(max),
  @P_NEW_ID int,
  @P_N_CRTDATE datetime2(0),
  @P_N_CRTUSER varchar(max),
  @P_TNAME varchar(max),
  @P_NAME varchar(max)


AS 

   BEGIN

         IF @P_EVENT = 'I'
            BEGIN

               INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE B(TABLENAME, ID, NAME)
                  VALUES (@P_TNAME, @P_NEW_ID, @P_NAME)

            END

END
```

**Questions to be clarified:**

- How to insert the data into TableA?
- To write the insert statement in Trigger, how to get all the attributes and its values in trigger?

Comment: I assume the RDBMS is SQL Server, but can you update your post and add this information?

Comment: Yes its SQL server. I have updated the same in question heading.,

Comment: I think that this whole thing can be simplified. Look into the SQL Merge command for table A, and the table B loos like just a log, so just do an insert to table B in the same stored procedure.